# Use Google Cloud Storage with GCS Library on Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to figure out how I can use Google Cloud Storage in my Android Application via the Google Cloud Storage Library.

So far I already use the appengine datastore to save some user data. However, to store images I want to use the Google Cloud Storage but I wasn't able to get it to work yet.

The official google "Getting started" does not really help and I can't find any other proper tutorial that tells me how this is done.

Can somebody please explain the basic steps that are needed or recommend a tutorial that works for using on android?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: have you found solution and/or good tutorial? Thanks

Comment: No I haven't and finnaly ended up using Google BlobStore. I think there are not many people who tried using Google Storage yet and therefore not many people know much about it.